# Why do I have to serve my webpage using http in order to use the Google API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am building an application to aid use of Google Sheets to keep track of company information. I had planned to use a Chrome extension for the app, but when I tried to load the Google API with JavaScript, I encountered an error. The [documentation for Google API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) reads this:

```
It only works within HTML documents with a <body> element served using the https (preferred) and http protocols.
```

I will probably not use a Chrome extension as the GUI for my app, as it requires the script to be loaded locally from the machine. My question is this: what is the point of this restriction? Is it more secure to use the Google API in a webpage coming from a server rather than a local browser application?

Additionally, what would be a good alternative for this kind of project? (it must be lightweight and able to interface with the Google Sheets API.)

Comment: Where did you read that comment?  Please add a link to the site that says that.

Comment: @SamBerlin Apologies, I added it.

Comment: Here's a few links that may help: https://github.com/GoogleDeveloperExperts/chrome-extension-google-apis , https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#the-standalone-auth-client , http://developer.streak.com/2014/10/how-to-use-gmail-api-in-chrome-extension.html?m=1 .  None are specific for the Sheets API, but the same steps should work.